# Get exact cursor position from UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView in which I need to insert the value at certain positions. For the purpose I need to get the cursor position. After a bit of browsing I came up with the following property to show the cursor position:

```
NSLog(@"%@", textView.selectedTextRange.start);
```

I used `NSLog` to find out in what format I get the output of the above expression. I got the output like the one below:

```
<UITextPosition: 0x7472ed0, 4, {"6554"}, {"333"}>
```

From the above set, all I need to get is just the value `4`. I couldn't see any method that can give me the value 4(which is the exact cursor position that I need). Is there any way that I can get the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Pposition relative to the beginning of the field
int pos = [self offsetFromPosition:self.beginningOfDocument 
                        toPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start];
```

Comment: Property 'beginningOfDocument' not fount on object of type 'ViewController *'

Comment: Its ok. Cleared it and got it. Thanks. :-)